# How to slow down playback speed of an audio file in Power Media Player--in Windows 10

Tags: software, sound-editing, playback, speed

This is an audio Police Interview and I am trying to identify the questions and answers. I am trying to make a document following a transcription type of method.  This has nothing to do with music, or anything of that sort.  I am trying to help someone and just have some answers I cannot make out because they are talking too fast for me to hear and understand.  I hope I have the correct forum to post this in.  If not, would  someone please direct me to the proper one?  I really know nothing about bitrates, syncing or anything technical. I just know there has to be a way to slow down the speed at which these people are speaking.  Do I need to download additional software and if so, what would that be? 
Again, I am using Power Media Player in Windows 10 and I am technically computer challenged.  Please advise if possible cause I am really struggling here.  Thank you so much.

Answer (score -1):

Is it playing fast or are they talking fast? Typically you need restoration software to clean up forensic audio. As well as eq. Windows media player will have no useful features. 
I'm not sure if your problem is because you perceive the audio as being too fast or its simply because the audio is of poor quality and you don't have critical ears to identify which it is.

Izotope has a software called RX5 that do a week long trial period that you could use, but fair warning you may find it difficult to use.